# Killing spinor on $S^6$

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, spinor

It is known that $S^6$ has (real) killing spinor. I am looking for an explicit description of such a spinor. More generally, we can choose an almost complex structure say, $J$ on $S^6$. Now, we can describe the spinors using $J$:
\begin{align*}
S_+\cong \Lambda_J^{0,0}\oplus \Lambda_J^{0,2}, S_-\cong \Lambda_J^{0,1}\oplus \Lambda_J^{0,3}
\end{align*}
Is there any known construction of any killing spinor using this description?

Comment: Yes.  Using the $\mathrm{G}_2$-invariant almost complex structure,  there is a $\mathrm{G}_2$-invariant $(0,3)$-form, and that corresponds to the killing spinor under the above isomorphisms.  The reason is that $S^6=\mathrm{G}_2/\mathrm{SU}(3)$, and $\mathrm{SU}(3)$ is the stabilizer of a $(0,3)$-form (unique up to a complex constant multiple).

Comment: @RobertBryant, so the killing spinor has to have both positive and negative spinor component. I am guessing the positive component comes from $\Lambda^{0,0}$?

Comment: Yes. That's correct.